# Canvas tamaño completo no funciona

Tags: javascript, canvas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Así se ve el fondo de canvas.. y aquí el código:***

```
     /* Área de programación */ 

    $(function(){
     var w = window;
        var d = document;
     var c = d.getElementById("c");   
     var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#111111"
     ctx.fillRect(0,0,w.innerWidth,w.innerHeight);    


    });




    /* Fin */

    <!doctype html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Área de programación</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>    
        <script src="programacion.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');

 h2 {color:white;text-align:center;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;padding-top: 5%;}


    </style>

    <body>
        <h2>Bienvenido a la sección de programación de Cosmos Theories</h2>

    </body>
    <canvas width="100%" height="100%" id="c"></canvas>
</html>
```

El main.css solo tiene esto:

```
@import url("n.css");
body {

    background-color: #CBCBCB;
    overflow-x: none;
    overflow-y: auto;

}
```

`n.css` ***es la libreria normalize***

***Y mi error, es que yo suponia que `window.innerWidth` y `window.innerHeight` me dibujarian un fillRect con canvas del tamaño de toda la ventana***

Cual es el error?

Answer (score 1):

Bueno es que una cosa es el tamaño del rectángulo y otra el tamaño del canvas. Para hacer que el canvas ocupe toda la pantalla puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

```
$(function(){
var w = window;
var d = document;
var c = d.getElementById("c");   
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.width = w.innerWidth;
c.height = w.innerHeight;
ctx.fillStyle = "#111111"
ctx.fillRect(0,0,w.innerWidth,w.innerHeight);
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que dar al `canvas` una altura y una anchura en el javascript

```js
var w = window;
var d = document;
var c = d.getElementById("c"); 
////////////////////////
c.width = w.innerWidth;
c.height= w.innerHeight;
////////////////////////
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#111111"
ctx.fillRect(0,0,w.innerWidth,w.innerHeight);
```

```html
<canvas width="100%" height="100%" id="c"></canvas>
```

Además en tu HTML tienes el `canvas` fuera del `body`